# When should i use @android:id/?

Tags: android

I've found some code examples with the `@android:id/xyz` attribute set instead of `@+id/xyz`.
When and why is it necessary to use Android ids instead of the user's id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@android:id` indicates that the id is in the `Android.r.id namespace`. So this is useful for ListActivities where they look for `Android.r.id.list` by default.

Answer (score 5):

The plus-symbol means that the resource is new and it must be created and added to the resources in the `R.java` file.

Omitting the plus symbol references an already existing resource.

Answer (score 2):

**@android** is used to access the default resources of Android .
For example see this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Using + sign means this resource must be added in R.java file while not using + sign means the resource already exist in R.java.

Comment: yes, i understand android:color or other attributes but don't' understand why use id attribute.

Comment: The '+' means to create the symbol if it doesn't already exist. You don't need it (and shouldn't use it) when referencing android: symbols, because those are already defined for you by the platform and you can't make your own in that namespace anyway.

Comment: id attribute is used to access the default resouces of Android.For example you can see **@android:id/list** used many times to access the default list odf android.