# difference between @android:id/* and @+id/*

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Today reading a tutorial i see the XML layout and see some elements have a id like

```
android:id="@android:id/element_id"
```

others have the regular `android:id`

```
android:id="@+id/element_id"
```

What is the difference between these two lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should i use @android:id/?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635826/when-should-i-use-androidid) ([Difference between “@id/” and “@+id/” in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android) may also be of interest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is using an ID defined by the Android framework (hence, the `android:` prefix).

The second one is declaring a new ID for use within your app.

Answer (score 2):

the one with the '+' will force the compiler to create that element in your R.java. You use the + when it is the first time creating a reference to that id. In other elements that refer to it, you do not need the '+' since its static entry in the R.java will already be there. A more eloquent explanation of this same issue is found here : [what is the difference betwenn @id/ and @+id/ in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731414/what-is-the-difference-betwenn-id-and-id-in-android)